# Want to verify that recommend counts come through like_count in FQL queries. So, total_count returns all shares, likes and recommends?

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-like, facebook-fql, recommendation-engine

Can someone please confirm that I can pull the number of users who have recommended a URL via the like_count in FQL queries? I want to confirm that total_count returns all shares, likes and recommends. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

https://graph.facebook.com/URL_ENCODED_LINK

At a minimum, it should return:

```
{
  "id": LINK, 
  "shares": COUNT_SHARES
}
```

Example for facebook.stackoverflow.com: https://graph.facebook.com/http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.stackoverflow.com

And result:

```
{
  "id": "http://facebook.stackoverflow.com", 
  "shares": 668
}
```

Update: Just noticed you want to use FQL queries. If the above doesn't work for you I'll take a look in the FQL tables, there should be something AFAIK :)